# Push ionic app to Bluemix

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-cloud

I am try to push my ionic app to bluemix using

```
cf push myApp
```

I am getting error:

```
Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack
FAILED
NoAppDetectedError
```

I am not sure which build pack i need for this app.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to push to Bluemix? Ionic is a FRONT-END framework for mobile apps. Bluemix is a BACK END service

Comment: @Ben Rondeau I meant how can I host my app on Bluemix for using its backend services.

Comment: Can you share the code you want to run on Bluemix? Otherwise it is impossible to help

Comment: @Ben Rondeau I am trying to run the ionic sample side menu app on blue mix using node.js, but i am fairly new to all this. http://plnkr.co/edit/0RXSDB?p=preview

Comment: That code needs to be loaded on your device. This is considered the front-end code